# Powering Arduino and motors on robot

Tags: power-supply

What is the recommend power scheme for an Arduino, dc and servo motors? The dc motor supply ranges from 3.5 to 7.5 volts. The power for the servo ranges from 5 to 6 volts. I'm using a 9.6 volt NiMH pack for the robot. I'm considering to use a l317 adjustable voltage regulator for the dc motor supply voltage and 9.6 for the Arduino. Could the servo be powered from the regulated 5 volts off of the Arduino ?

Comment: If you add the current requirements of everything, it will be easier for us to answer.

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure how much current the robot draws. I would say when running less < 1 amp. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the number of servos you want to use. Anything more than one is not recommended to run off of the Arduino's 5v rail. You'd need a shield like [this one](http://www.frys.com/product/7726928?source=google&gclid=Cj0KEQiA3t-2BRCKivi-suDY24gBEiQAX1wiXJMNMcB1pmTwylHFkA6fCdDnpADZt7zzRFo1mmZfXgkaAp8j8P8HAQ) to properly run multiple servos, as you could connect a separate power source to the shield to avoid putting stress on the Arduino's power regulator. The shield could also run the motors you'd use in your project! The only other recommendation I have is to consider investing in a Lithium Polymer battery, as I've found those are generally better suited for projects like this.